# Network tries to reindentify itself now and then

Tags: windows-7, networking

When the computer starts up it connects itself to the router (ZTE 4G router) automatically, but after I have surfed the web for a while, it tries to identify itself, meaning you get that little blue circle next to the little screen at the corner.
When browsing it does not cause any problems, but if I'm streaming a video the video will then stop, I'll have to refresh the page to make the video start again. And if I'm playing a game, LoL for example, the game will freeze for about 2 seconds then continue again (due to lost connection to the internet).

I have no virus on my computer, although I had before. I have reset my router, restarted my computer, updated my ethernet driver, checked so that the IPv4 is set on automatic and tried different router channels. I have had this router for a few months and the problem just started recently.

Here is the ipconfig screen:

[image: ipconfig output]

Comment: I edited your question, if you are unhappy with the changes feel free to revert them or edit again.